# How to differentiate between two dynamic url in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two dynamic url with simillar structure. For example, lets say, `Product` page and `category` page.

I have set both pages in

```
Route::get('/{product}', [UsersController:: class, 'productDetail']);
Route::get('/{category}', [UsersController:: class, 'categoryProducts']);
```

But when I click on url which suppose to go in category page, it redirect to product page only because of same structure. How I can differentiate both URLs for Laravel without altering their url structure?

Comment: You should add more code in detail. What is content of `productDetail` and `categoryProducts`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done without modifying the URL pattern at least a little bit.

If you do something like `/50?type=category` then in the `show` method you can use the query parameter to determine which table to look at. But you'll have to use the same `show` method and I don't recommend doing it this way.

I hope someone else will be able to shine some more light on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

this is the best practice for your case to make yourapi Resful

```
Route::get('/product/{product-id}', [UsersController:: class, 'productDetail']); 
Route::get('/product/categories, [UsersController:: class, 'categoryProducts']);
```

learn more about Restful api here https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Answer (score 0):

This should be done by calling index, update `diff()` function. You can try by using the below:

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}', 'site\categorycontroller@show')->name('category.show');
Route::get('/product/{slug}', 'site\productcontroller@show')->name('product.show');
```